# Filter Condition Difference - Where Clause vs Join Condition

Tags: join

Quick easy filter question.

What would be the difference in output, or what impact would it have moving a filter condition out of a WHERE clause into the Join condition.

For example:

```
Select a1.Name, a2.State
from student a1
left join location a2 on a1.name_id = a2.name_id
where a1.name LIKE 'A%'
and a2.state = 'New York';
```

To This:

```
Select a1.Name, a2.State
from student a1
left join location a2 on (a1.name_id = a2.name_id) and a2.state = 'New York'
where a1.name LIKE 'A%';
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) will show student names that begins with "A" and whose location is New York.
2) will show all student names that begin with "A" , 'New York' if student state is New York, or null in other cases ( there is no corresponding state, or student state is not New York)

Difference between (1) and (2) - (1) will not have non-New York students.

Comment: But, if it was an `inner join`, there would be no difference?

Comment: Yes , for `inner join` it will be no difference in resultset. However, in my opinion, having join condition in `ON ` and filters in `WHERE` improves readability  and ,as a result,  maintainability .

Answer (score 11):

[@a1ex07 's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196040/22336) is entirely correct. However, let's provide a bit more general answer.

When you have a `TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b` scenario, then you have to be careful how you use `TableB` fields in your `WHERE` clause.

For any rows in `TableA` where there is no matching row in `TableB`, all fields in `TableB` will be set to NULL.

Let's look at your example.

We'll assume that that you want all rows from `TableA` (`student`) that either have no matching row in `TableB` (`location`), *or* that have a matching row in `TableB` where `b.Column1` (`location.State`) equals "New York".

1. If your `WHERE` clause includes a check on a `TableB` field that doesn't allow for a NULL value in that field, all the `TableA` rows without a matching `TableB` row will be excluded.

   Example: `WHERE b.State = 'New York'` - `TableA` rows with no matching `TableB` rows would have `B.Column1` as NULL. Since `NULL = 'New York'` is not TRUE, none of the `TableA` (`student`) rows without a matching `TableB` (`location`) row meet the criteria in the `WHERE` clause.

   In effect, this makes the `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`.
2. If you *do* allow for `TableB` values to be NULL, you need to be careful that you don't allow in more values than you mean.

   If you change the above example `WHERE` clause to:

   ```
   WHERE (b.State = 'New York' OR b.State IS NULL)
   ```

   Then `TableA` rows without a matching `TableB` row will still be included. However, so will `TableA` rows *with* a matching `TableB` row where `Column1` is set to NULL (in your case, `student` rows with a matching `location` row, where the `location.State` is NULL). That may not be the intent.
3. To actually meet our assumed intent, you have at least two options:

   - First, you can put the restriction on `TableB` rows in the `JOIN` condition:

     ```
     FROM TableA a
            LEFT JOIN TableB b ON (a.name_id = b.name_id AND b.State = 'New York')
     ```

     This lets through all `TableA` (`student`) rows where there's no matching `TableB` (`location`) row; where there *is* a matching `TableB` row, the matched rows from `TableA` and `TableB` will only be included if `b.State` is "New York".
   - Second, include your check in the `WHERE` clause, but use the `JOIN` column in `TableB` to allow for NULLs:

     ```
     FROM TableA a
            LEFT JOIN TableB b ON (a.name_id = b.name_id)
     WHERE (b.State = 'New York' OR b.name_id IS NULL)
     ```

     This assumes that `a.name_id` cannot be NULL. Then, the only way `b.name_id` can be NULL is if there was no match found for the `JOIN` in `TableB`. Again, `TableA` rows without a `TableB` match are included (because `b.name_id` will always be NULL for those rows). With our assumption, where `TableA` has a matching `TableB` row, `b.name_id` will *never* be NULL, so `b.State` *must* be "New York" for this `TableA` and `TableB` matched pair of rows to be included.

Comment: Excellent explanation. For those who need a refresher to understand what @RDFozz is talking about-- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins